# Delete a document from Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a document from a collection called "photo" but it doesn't work, there is no OnFailureException message as OnSuccess Toast is shown but the document still remain in the Firestore :(

Structure of the firestore:
[image]

This is the codes I use to delete the document:

```
        Photo photo = (Photo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("photo");

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        CollectionReference photoRef = db.collection("main").document(userId).collection("photo");
```

```
DocumentReference document = photoRef.document(photo.getId());
                    String currentDocumentID = document.getId();
                    photoRef.document(currentDocumentID).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(ViewPhotoActivity.this, "Entry Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(ViewPhotoActivity.this, PhotoActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ViewPhotoActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are several ways to do this which includes the answer I received above, the getID method is a little confusing to me as it doesn't work sometimes or give me a null exception, so I changed my code and use a simpler way, which is to create a unique ID for each document when they are being created, then set the document Id with that unique ID so I could retrieve them easily, for this case, I created the ID by combining the title and 6 random digits.

When creating the document, I added a unique ID field for each document:

```
//set a unique ID for each photo
                String randomSixNumbers = getRandomNumberString();
                String photoId = (title.toLowerCase() + randomSixNumbers).replace(" ", "").trim();

//set ID to new object 
              Photo photo = new Photo(photoId, title, photoDescription, filePath, datePhoto);

//add object to firestore and set document ID as the uniqueID instead of the default auto-generated documentID                 
              photoRef.document(photoId).set(photo).addOnSuccessListener(...
```

delete the document using the unique ID:

```
photoRef.document(photo.getId()).delete().addOnSuccessListener(...
```

For now, this process seems okay, though I am not sure if it is a good practice or not? If not, could someone point out the downside/fault of this method?

And I noticed that I have to use intent to get the data passing from last activity to get the object data in current activity.

Answer (score 2):

*I am writing the answer from speculation as there is not enough information as to how you are creating the document.*

```
DocumentReference document = photoRef.document(photo.getId());
```

In the above line you are creating a reference to a document with photo id. Looking at the document data it seems the **photo id is not same as the document id**.

Therefore when you create the above reference- you are not referring to the existing document with `id="2BMG3..."` rather a NEW document with `id="jYBPX..."`

```
String currentDocumentID = document.getId();
photoRef.document(currentDocumentID).delete()
```

How you can fix it depends on how you want to save/create the documents. One way could be to create the documents in `photo` collection with `id= photo id` in the first place.

For example, when creating, you could create the document reference as following:

```
CollectionReference photoRef = db.collection("main")
                                .document(userId)
                                .collection("photo")
                                .document(photo.getId());
```

And then set the data as:

```
photoRef.set(photo);
```

That'd set the data to a document you have created with `id=photo id`.

These examples can be improved if you show how you're adding documents to `photo` collection now. If you've been using `.colection('photo').add()` or `.collection.document().set(photo)` then the created document would have an auto-generated id different from the photo id.

Comment: Hi, could you also show me how to set the id = photo id in the first place?

Comment: @Lionlollipop Updated the answer with examples, if still unclear please add to post some snippet of how you are creating the documents, then the examples can be more relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very useful :)